# PHP SQL JOIN STATEMENT with related columns

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this code below. I am getting a broken screen. I think it is in the sql statement but maybe someone can help spot my mistake. What I am doing here is to make a record of documents requested by the administrators from customers with date requested by admin and posted by customer. Along with a lot of other information.

I want to pull the document information from the document center table by joining the document id column in the document center with the docId column in the documents requested table. The goal is so that I don't have to repeat the same document information on both tables such as file name and title as well as doctype which helps the script figure out what directory the file will be stored in. The docId in the documents requested table is the same id in the doc center table.

```
        if($res = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT dr.id, dr.custId, dr.docId, dr.dateRequested, dr.requestedBy, dr.modifiedOn,
                                              dr.datePosted, dc.document, dc.documentTitle, dc.docType, dc.id
                                              FROM docsRequested dr
                                              INNER JOIN docCenter dc ON dr.docId=dc.id
                                              WHERE dr.custId = '$this->custId' LIMIT 0, 3")){
            while($data = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            $docId = $data['dr.id'];
            if($data['dc.docType'] == 'img'){
                $filedir = "img";
            } elseif($data['dc.docType'] == 'pdf') {
                $filedir = "loandocs";
            }
            printf("<th><a href=\"edit-doc.php?username=$this->username&id=$docId&custId=$this->custId\"> <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\"> Edit </button></a></th>
                    <th><a href=\"delete-doc.php?username=$this->username&id=$docId&custId=$this->custId\"> <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\"> Delete </button></a></th>
                    <th><a href=\"%s/%s\">%s</a></th>
                    <th>%s</th>
                    <th>%s</th>
                    <th>%s</th>
                    <th>%s</th>
                    <th>%s</th>
                    </tr>", $filedir, $data['dc.document'], $data['dc.documentTitle'], $data['dr.dateRequested'], $data['dr.requestedBy'], $data['dc.docType'], $data['dr.datePosted'], $data['dr.modifiedOn']);
            }
        }
```

I also tried using `SELECT dr.*, dc.*` in the sql statement to skip calling each column one by one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if($res = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT dr.id AS dr_id, dr.custId, dr.docId, dr.dateRequested, dr.requestedBy, dr.modifiedOn,
                                              dr.datePosted, dc.document, dc.documentTitle, dc.docType, dc.id AS dc_id
                                              FROM docsRequested dr
                                              INNER JOIN docCenter dc ON dr.docId=dc.id
                                              WHERE dr.custId = '$this->custId' LIMIT 0, 3"))

after your fetch assoc use this :
$data['dr_id'] and $data['dc_id'];
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: IDK what the answer is but I can see what he did here and my only question is once dc.id is changed to dc_id in the select query, does that have any effect in the "ON" section where it says "ON dr.docId=dc.id" does the dc.id in this section change to dc_id or we keep the original one as it is now before getting to the fetch?

Comment: @RookieRecruits `ON` and `WHERE` can only reference columns in the original tables, they can't refer to aliases created in the `SELECT` clause of the same query.